# How to test for ext4 Partition? Not ext4 Filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Start Update Question due to someone deleted information:
No interest in testing for `ext4` Filesystem.

```
lsblk -n -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1          #confirms filesystem ext4 on my computer 
findmnt /dev/sdb1                     #specifies FSTYPE ext4 & options
```

Above 2 commands have `ext4` output on my computer but are of no interest.
No interest in testing for `ext4` Filesystem.

Hint:
5 different UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers) with
2 commands:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdb* |sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' |grep 'UUID'  #3 UUIDs, each 36 characters
```

```
  PTUUID="1de2a9d6-d417-45e8-9f57-5fab1e009781"
    UUID="0fadb867-8a34-47ec-be38-03fa56fda6ed"
PARTUUID="00431bd0-1286-4a11-bfca-8e76cc88c97f"
```

and

`sudo fdisk -x`

```
Type-UUID                            UUID  
0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 00431BD0-1286-4A11-BFCA-8E76CC88C97F
```

End Update

Interest is the command to test for `ext4` Partition?

According to reference below,
`"A partition can have a type."`

"(you can put whatever file-system wherever you want –
just do not expect things to work out of the box)."

refer:
Why does parted need a Filesystem type when creating a partition, and how does its action differ from a utility like mkfs.ext4?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551030/why-does-parted-need-a-filesystem-type-when-creating-a-partition-and-how-does-i

regarding command with optional `ext4` flag
`sudo parted -a opt /dev/sd_ mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%`
sd_=sda or sdb ...

Why test for `ext4` Partition?
When disk was Partitioned ...
to give evidence that the first command below was done
not second command :

```
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sd_ mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%   #cmd1
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sd_ mkpart primary      0% 100%   #cmd2
```

Again,
How to test for `ext4` Partition?  Not `ext4` Filesystem.
What is the command?

--

Comment: There are several questions here. Which one is *the* question? Which one is a citation? Which one is rhetorical?

Comment: Kamil typed, "Which one is the question?" Answer:
How to test for ```ext4``` Partition?  Not ```ext4``` Filesystem.   
__ Said differently, what evidence does ```parted``` command leave on disk 
that ```ext4``` optional flag was issued?  see command 
```sudo parted -a opt /dev/sd_ mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%```   .

Comment: If we consider classic MBR + partition table, partition type is just one byte value. What do you want to test? What is there to test? The question makes very little sense. Clarify what you're asking  by editing the OP rather than add comments.

Comment: "to give evidence that the first command below was done, not second command" – In my tests there was no difference. It seems `parted mkpart` without `fs-type` uses the same id for the new partition as `parted mkpart` with `ext4`. This is 0x83 (Linux) in msdos partition table and 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 (Linux filesystem) in GPT. So these are the defaults. Randomly created IDs (if any) may and will differ. I think **your two commands are equivalent**. What practical problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Kamil, What commands did you run? to show "0x83 (Linux) in 
msdos partition table and 
0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 (Linux filesystem) in GPT."

Comment: Kamil typed, "What practical problem are you trying to solve?"  
Which command to use.  
Above #cmd1 with ```ext4``` or 
Above #cmd2 without ```ext4```.  
Which command to run manually or run in a script.

Comment: In question, the reference page at unix.stackexchange.com states 
```"A partition can have a type."``` and 
```"(you can put whatever file-system wherever you want –  
just do not expect things to work out of the box)."```  
Above reference suggests:  
above #cmd1 with ```ext4``` is 
more compatible, more stable, less problems for a 
GPT partition table, 
GPT Partition like sdb1, 
FSTYPE ```ext4``` format.

Comment: I did run `fdisk -x`. It's probably not the best command for scripting, but my point was (and still is) that your two `parted` commands seem equivalent, i.e. by just examining the device there is no way to "give evidence that the first command below was done not second command".

Comment: Note Question Update.  including ```sudo blkid /dev/sdb* |sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' |grep 'UUID'```  #3 UUIDs, each 36 characters and including ```fdisk -x``` in update.

Answer (score 1):

The `mkpart` command does not actually create the file system: the `fs-type` parameter [`ext4` in your case] will simply be used by parted to set **partition type GUID** for GPT partitions or **partition type ID** for MBR partitions to show "Linux Filesystem".

It's just another way to identify or label what that partition is, which you can view with other partition tools like `fdisk -l`. Mostly used when identifying swap/raid/lvm partitions in my own experience.

As you've seen, `parted` groups many `fs-type` names like `ext2` and `ext4` into a single ID/GUID for "Linux Filesystem". A list of known IDs and names is maintained on [wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Parted#Partition_schemes

Comment: The most interesting part is actually what follows your quote, in the green box: there is just one partition type ID for all Linux filesystems. // `df` does not deal with partitions at all, only with mounted filesystems.

Comment: @DanielB edited `df` to `fdisk`, thank you! That's what I get for going from memory

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an "ext4" partition. A partition containing an ext4 filesystem would usually (but not necessarily, all of my Linux filesystems are in partitions with type identifiers identical to those of Windows NTFS partitions) have a partition type GUID (in the case of a GPT) or a one-byte partition id (in the case of the old msdos partition table) that indicates a "Linux filesystem data".